# How can I start to write Unit test in web Scrapy using python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, web-scraping, scrapy

```
class AljazeeraSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "aljazeera"
    allowed_domains = ["aljazeera.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.aljazeera.com/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)  # The xPath selector
        titles = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class,"SkyScrapperBoxes")]/div[contains(@class,"skyscLines")]')
        if not titles:
            MailNotify().send_mail("Aljazeera", "Scraper Report")

        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = NewsItem()
            item['title'] = escape(''.join(titles.select('a/text()').extract()))
            item['link'] = "http://www.aljazeera.com" + escape(''.join(titles.select('a/@href').extract()))
            item['description'] = ''
            item = Request(item['link'], meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_detail)
            items.append(item)

        return items

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        detail = sel.select('//td[@class = "DetailedSummary"]')
        item['details'] = remove_html_tags(escape(''.join(detail.select('p').extract())))
        item['location'] = ''
        published_date = sel.select('//span[@id = "ctl00_cphBody_lblDate"]')
        item['published_date'] = escape(''.join(published_date.select('text()').extract()))

        return item
```

I am currently working on Scrapy to crawl the website. I have some knowledge about unittest in python. But,How can I write the unittest to check that link is working, and `item['location']`, `item['details']` are returning the value or not? I have learned Scrapy contract but cannot understand anything.So, how can write the unittest in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we are talking specifically about how to test the spiders (not pipelines, or loaders), then what we did is provided a "fake response" from a local HTML file. Sample code:

```
import os
from scrapy.http import Request, TextResponse

def fake_response(file_name=None, url=None):
    """Create a Scrapy fake HTTP response from a HTML file"""
    if not url:
        url = 'http://www.example.com'

    request = Request(url=url)
    if file_name:
        if not file_name[0] == '/':
            responses_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            file_path = os.path.join(responses_dir, file_name)
        else:
            file_path = file_name

        file_content = open(file_path, 'r').read()
    else:
        file_content = ''

    response = TextResponse(url=url, request=request, body=file_content,
                            encoding='utf-8')
    return response
```

Then, in your `TestCase` class, call the `fake_response()` function and feed the response to the `parse()` callback:

```
from unittest.case import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.spider = MySpider()

    def test_parse(self):
        response = fake_response('input.html')
        item = self.spider.parse(response)
        self.assertEqual(item['title'], 'My Title')
        # ...
```

---

Aside from that, you should definitely start using [`Item Loaders`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with input and output processors - this would help to achieve a better modularity and, hence, isolation - spider would just yield item instances, data preparation and modification would be incapsulated inside the loader, which you would test separately.